# I need to find and replace \n in a mysql field

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

i've got data like this:

1 street\n2street\nmycity\nmytown

What i want to do is replace \n with char(10) as i need a real linebreak in the db field.

I've got:

```
UPDATE data set `value` = REPLACE(`value`,'\n', char(10)) WHERE `key`='shipping_address';
```

But that is not working.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: are you getting any error or you are not getting what you want.

Comment: This should work for all entries in the table `data` that have a field `key` with the value 'shipping_address'. However I assume that you wanted to replace in every single entry of the whole data table. For this simply omit the whole `WHERE` part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE data set `value` = REPLACE(`value`,'\\n', CHAR(10)) WHERE `key`='shipping_address';
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to escape the `\` like this:

```
UPDATE data set `value` = REPLACE(`value`,'\\n', char(10)) WHERE `key`='shipping_address';
```

Comment: That worked for the most part. I had to change it from char(10)+char(13) to char(10) as using your code inserted '0' in place of the \n. Which was weird as you have specified the right char codes there, i had forgotten about char(13). Cheers though!

Comment: Yep sorry, @aF, i wanted to give you that tick, but it wasn't quote right and i saw someone else had given the right answer sooo i had to give it to them. My sincere aplogies ;)

Answer (score 1):

Double the backslash to escape it and treat it as a literal:

```
UPDATE data set `value` = REPLACE(`value`,'\\n', char(10)) WHERE `key`='shipping_address';
```

Answer (score 1):

New line character is either '\n' (Line Feed) or '\r' (Carriage return) individually, or CR followed by LF '\r\n' depending on the os.

```
UPDATE data set `value` = REPLACE(`value`,'\r' or '\n' or '\r\n', char(10)) WHERE `key`='shipping_address';
```

Answer (score 0):

My case: It didn't work because I thought that it had \n but it had \r

```
update [Table] set [column]=replace(convert([column] using utf8) ,'\r','');
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to actually replace line endings in my columns. This worked for me:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET
`column` = REPLACE(`column`, char(13), '');
```

char(13) is carriage return and char(10) is line feed. You may have either.