# Manipulate data in the front with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select

I have a problem and I am stuck, really bad... and I was wondering if anyone can help me out with this one, any help would be really appreciated,, the problem is the following,,

I have a mysql table table_n and i m getting data from specific rows using select to show in the front like that,

```
SELECT dtstart,summary,description FROM table_n ORDER BY dtstart DESC
```

is working fine, BUT

the column `description` has data in every row like that ,

Name = George\nSurname = Papadopoulos\nEmail = gggg@mmmmm.com\nTelephone = 69555444455\nGender = Male\n

Name = Nick\nSurname = Stam\nEmail = ffffg@mffmmm.com\nTelephone = 695443334455\nGender = Male\n

and so in...........so with the above select I display in the front exactly what is inside each row...

BUT I want to remove every \n and put in its place a comma in order to show like that,

Name = George,Surname = Papadopoulos,Email = gggg@mmmmm.com,Telephone = 69555444455,Gender = Male

Name = Nick,Surname = Stam,Email = ffffg@mffmmm.com,Telephone = 695443334455,Gender = Male

ans so in..........

i dont want to touch the database,,,i mean i just want the sql query that will acieve the above only in the front!!,,

as i said i dont want to touch the table and change any data inside the table.

is this possible to make it with sql query ?

i hope its clear enough

Thank you guys in advance, any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Looks like someone was lazy when they wrote a CSV import. Data in this form is pretty much useless. Have you considered refactoring `table_n` to include columns `Name, Surname, Email, Telephone, Gender`? I get that you don't "want" to refactor the table, but I think you'll be saving yourself a lot of trouble if you do.

Comment: [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) time me thinks

Comment: Thank you Bob for the quick response, but as i said i dont to touch the table... Drew u mean Extract, transform, load ?

Comment: Parse data _before_ inserting, then put it into as many separate columns/tables as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use replace function and replace `\n` with `,`
[stackoverflow.com/questions/9362213/i-need-to-find-and-replace-n-in-a-mysql-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362213/i-need-to-find-and-replace-n-in-a-mysql-field)

Comment: Yeah but that's what OP wants.

Comment: yeah here one person speaks for all ;)

Comment: Guys listen, thank you all,, but the question is very clear!!! I dont want to touch the db!!! the replace works with update that make changes to the table,, as i said i dont want to make changes to the db table....  just want in the front to make the change..... NOT the db table.. is this possible>? this is the question !

Comment: Replace is just a function. If you dont ask it to update then why would it update? Just use `select dtstart,summary,replace(description,•••) from •••••` and you will get what you want

Comment: Utsav i have  a last question if i may ask ??!!,,, the select i m using is with custom names for the column titles... like that,

Comment: SELECT dtstart Date,summary Summary,description Problem FROM table_n ORDER BY dtstart DESC ,,, but now is like that   SELECT dtstart,summary,replace(description Problem,'//n',' ') FROM table_n ORDER BY dtstart DESC and i m getting an error cause i cant rename the column description with a title Problem,,, even if i do it like that     SELECT dtstart,summary,replace(description,'\\n',' ') FROM table_n ORDER BY dtstart DESC  i get a column title replace(description,'\\n',' ')  how can i do it to have a column title Problem ??

Comment: `SELECT dtstart Date,summary Summary,replace(description,'\\n',' ') Problem FROM table_n ORDER BY dtstart DESC`. Try this. These are just alias which would act as column name in your select query.