# How to search and replace empty html table rows with line breaks in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to search and replace this html in a mysql database ( via phpMyAdmin ) :

```
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

But I don't know how to find it, as it has line breaks.

My current query is :

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
 SET `post_content` = replace(post_content, '<tr>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                              </tr>', '')
```

But obviously, it's not working.

How can I target it ?

Comment: Please provide sample data. It is unclear if you are looking to replace 4 different strings, or a string with 4 lines.

Comment: @GMB looks like a four-line string to me

Comment: Try to use `\\n` instead of newlines in replace

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? If it's 8.0+ (or even MariaDB 10+), this will be easier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to find and replace \n in a mysql field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362213/i-need-to-find-and-replace-n-in-a-mysql-field)

Comment: Also, it's _"obviously not working"_ because you not only have newlines but 30 spaces before the start of each line in your _from_str_ string

Comment: GMB I provided a sample data, it was the first snippet, a four-line string. My mysql version is 5.6.35.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to replace *a string made of 4 lines*, one thing you need to be careful about is line breaks. For example in your query you have additional spaces at the beginning of lines 2, 3 and 4, that probably will not match.

Depending on your set up, line breaks could be `\r\n` or `\n`.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_content` = REPLACE(
    post_content, 
    '<tr>\n<td></td>\n<td></td>\n</tr>', 
    ''
  )
```

---

If you are looking to replace *4 different strings*, then you could either run the updates one by one, or generate a 4-level deedp nested `REPLACE()`. Here are examples for two string parts :

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(post_content, '<tr>', '');
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(post_content, '<td></td>', '');
```

Or :

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` 
SET `post_content` = 
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
             post_content, 
            '<td></td>',
            ''
        ),
        '<tr>', 
        ''
    )
;
```

Comment: Would someone please explain the anonymous downvote ? If anything is wrong with my answer I am willing to improve it.

Comment: Well the other solution seems better because it's watching for any space/line break between elements but the regex_replace functions is not working for me ... but your first snippet works like a charm, i needed to replace both `\n` and `\r\n`. Thank's !

Answer (score 2):

you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`. Please note that the provided regex both works for windows and linux style newlines. please also note that possible use of spaces are also considered in regex.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(x, '<tr>(\s*\r*\n*\s*<td>\s*\r*\n*\s*</td>){2}\s*\r*\n*\s*</tr>', '<<replaced>>' )
```

- `\n` is linux style newline
- `\r\n` is windows style newline
- `\s` is space character

> ```
> create table t (x varchar(1000));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values ('before <tr>\n<td></td>\n<td></td>\n</tr> after')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from t
> ```
>
> ```
> | x                                                    |
> | :--------------------------------------------------- |
> | before <tr><br><td></td><br><td></td><br></tr> after |
> ```

> ```
> select REGEXP_REPLACE(x, '<tr>(\s*\r*\n*\s*<td>\s*\r*\n*\s*</td>){2}\s*\r*\n*\s*</tr>', '<<replaced>>' ) from t
> ```
>
> ```
> | REGEXP_REPLACE(x, '<tr>(\s*\r*\n*\s*<td>\s*\r*\n*\s*</td>){2}\s*\r*\n*\s*</tr>', '<<replaced>>' ) |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | before <<replaced>> after                                                                         |
> ```

> ```
> update t set x = REGEXP_REPLACE(x, '<tr>(\s*\r*\n*\s*<td>\s*\r*\n*\s*</td>){2}\s*\r*\n*\s*</tr>', '<<replaced>>' )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d394fdb1e27da0dacdbaafd6557f737)*